# Fetch phase elapsed time when searching in Elasticsearch using Spark

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark

I make queries to Elasticsearch using Spark. As it says in the documentation Spark creates tasks accordingly to the number of Elasticsearch shards (e.g. for 32 shards there will be 32 Spark tasks). Each task connects and retrieves data from separate Elasticsearch shard.

Also there is a description of fetch phase (from [Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide — Distributed Search Execution » Fetch Phase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_fetch_phase.html)):

> The distributed phase consists of the following steps:
>
> 1. The coordinating node identifies which documents need to be fetched
>      and issues a multi GET request to the relevant shards.
> 2. Each shard loads the documents and enriches them, if required, and
>      then returns the documents to the coordinating node.
> 3. Once all documents have been fetched, the coordinating node returns
>      the results to the client.

In Elasticsearch-Spark solution we have different algorithm since there is no coordinating node:

1. Shard loads the documents and enriches them, if required.
2. Elasticsearch returns the shard results to the client (Spark task).

My question is as follows:

I look at the elapsed time of fetch phase in the slow log. Does elapsed time includes the transfer of all data from shard to client (Spark task)? Or it includes only time to retrieve data from filesystem?

Comment: That just includes the retrieval time from the Lucene index. You have to remember that Elasticsearch logs are specific to elasticsearch whereas Spark task are mainly logged into your cluster logs.

Comment: @eliasah, thanks for your reply. It is interesting that it is only time to retrieve data from Lucene index. I retrieve a big amount of data (about 500K docs). It usually takes about 10 seconds. I have ES cluster with 8 EC2 m4.2xlarge instances. I'd monitored the CPU and disk usage and observed that disk usage is absent (no read operations), but CPU is quite high (up to 50%). I think this is due to the fact that data is cached in filesystem cache. But why does it take so much time to retrieve data from cache?

Comment: Usually Lucene segments are in RAM. Nevertheless, I'm afraid I can't answer your question with the given information.